# Validating if two fields are the same in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In my form, I have two fields `pass` and `pass_repeat`. On the browser side, I validate it using javascript. On the server-side I want to check whether they are the same. How can I do it using `request()->validate()` method?

I can check the equality with `php`, however, I'd like to know if it is possible with `request()->validate()` or not.

Even keywords for further search are appreciated.

P.S. My try:

```
$result = request()->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30', 'min:8'],
        'password_repeat' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30', 'min:8']
    ]);
if ($result['password' != $result['password_repeat'] || $result['password_repeat'] == '' || $result['password'] == '')
{
   abort();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried, post your code

Comment: @sta I've updated the post and added the smallest working code.

Comment: [Validation#Rule Same](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-same)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-confirmed

Comment: @JohnLobo Thanks. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @JuanEizmendi That's very good in the sense that it can confirm two fields with different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the name of input 'password_repeat' to 'password_confirmation' in your form and use validator 'confirmed'

```
$result = request()->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30', 'min:8','confirmed'],
        
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

you are doing this in a wrong way, laravel has [`confirmed rule`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-confirmed) that can be use for confirmation purposes, you should add `pass_confirmation` input and pass it to controller via form and use `confirmed` rule for `pass` input.